# ASP.NET: Json get 404 not found

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery-plugins, grid

I am trying to run one of the sample programs given by [EditableGrid](http://www.editablegrid.net/en) to run on my localhost with asp.net. It is that of loading json data example. It throws an exception saying:

```
GET http://localhost:60218/grid.json?22895 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the line where it occurs:

```
editableGrid.loadJSON("grid.json");
```

The JSON file is placed in my solution hierarchy as well..I am new to editablegrids, so have no clue what is going wrong here?? I also do not happen to find any or no help on editablegrids, should I be using this for grids? Or should I be looking into other plugins? Other that JQGrid...More or less similar to editablegrid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is very clear - the EditableGrid is run under php !

If you wish to mix php with asp.net you may try it, but is not work for the small web server that visual studio use for test and debug.

Comment: yes...so I presume...no concrete documentation or tutorials makes it even more difficult..switching to some other clientside control now..thanks anyways..

Comment: @faizanjehangir find one for asp.net !

Comment: I am looking into slickgrid now...heard some good reviews about it...will give it a try now!